# Регулярное выражение для вырезания предложений

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно регулярное выражение, которое "вырезает" каждое предложение из текста. Разделителем может служить точка и большая буква новой строки.

Я написал regex `"(\w+\s?)+\.\s?$?"`, оно вырезает такие предложения:

> Some sentences. Than must be extracted. By a regular expression.

Но не корректно работает с предложениями у которых есть какие либо символы, типа ", - '" и так далее, так же не работает с кириллическими символами.

Нужно решить задачу без использования split.

Comment: Дайте пример некорректных предложений

Comment: Some, sentences. With symbols like ',' or '-'. Или же кириллические символы. For example-this. (Такие предложения не работают, а должны)

Comment: попробуйте это `[A-ZА-Я]{1}[^\.]+\.?`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, In computing, plain text is a loose term for data (e.(ЛОМАЕТСЯ В ЭТОМ МЕСТЕ, считает за конец предложения)g. file contents) that...

Comment: In computing, plain text is a loose term for data (e.g. file contents) that....  Это исходное предложение

Comment: `[A-ZА-Я]{1}[^A-ZА-Я]+\.?\s?`

Comment: Можно ли предположить, что предложения, которые вы хотите извлечь, всегда разделены знаками `?`, `!` или `.`, за которыми следует 1 и более пробельных символов, за которыми следует заглавная буква? Т.е. `(?Us).*?(?:[?!.]\s+\p{Lu}|$)`?

Answer (score 0):

Если предположить, что предложения, которые вы хотите извлечь, всегда разделены знаками `?`, `!` или `.`, за которыми следует 1 и более пробельных символов, за которыми следует заглавная буква, то можно использовать

```
String regex = "(?Us).*?(?:[?!.]\\s+\\p{Lu}|$)";
```

**Подробности**

- `(?Us)` - модификаторы, позволяющие классам вроде `\s` находить все пробельные символы Юникода (`(?U)`) и . находить символы перехода на новую строку (`(?s)`)
- `.*?` - 0 и более любых символов
- `(?:[?!.]\\s+\\p{Lu}|$)` - незахватывающая подмаска с двумя альтернативами:

  - `[?!.]\\s+\\p{Lu}` - `?`, `!` или `.`, затем 1+ пробельных символов и заглавная буква
  - `|` - или
  - `$` - конец строки.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше регулярное выражение верно, но чтобы включить кириллицу, надо поставить флаг unicode  ((?U)).

Далее, вам нужно разделять предложения по запятым и по дефису:

([\w+|\w+\,-]\s?)+[.]\s?

вот тут можно посмотреть работающий пример
https://regex101.com/r/yj8OoI/1